# SVD optimization formula

Tags: svd

Does anyone know what convex optimization formula (Objective function) results in the singular value decomposition or Principle component analysis of matrix X (n by p)?

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues (singular values) maximize Rayleigh quotients --
that's how iterative methods for the top few singular values work.
Also, for rank-r approximation, wikipedia [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) cites the Eckart-Young theorem:
SVD minimizes |M - Mr| over Mr in the (rather nonconvex) set of rank-r matrices, in Frobenius norm.
See also the table under [pca-lda-cca-and-pls](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23353/pca-lda-cca-and-pls).

Answer (score 1):

The largest singular value can be computed as the maximum of u^T X v, for u and v of norm one.

Another formula can be derived from the Rayleigh quotients by taking into account that the singular values are the square root of the eigenvalues of the matrix X^T X. In this case, the largest singular value can be seen as the maximum of ||Xv|| for v unit norm. The rest of singular values can be derived from the [min-max principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values)